# .Net Lazy Initialization of a Singleton property

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, singleton, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I have a class, `DataAdapter` which is instantiated as a singleton object by my site. That class has a Person property which I'd like to be a lazy singleton, the code to accomplish this:

```
private readonly object _personLock = new object();
private volatile IPersonManager _person;
public IPersonManager Person
{
    get
    {
        if (_person == null)
        {
            lock (_personLock)
            {
                if (_person == null)
                {
                    _person = new PersonManager(_adUserName, _adPassword, client);
                }
            }
        }
        return _person;
    }
}
```

(those three arguments to the PersonManager constructor are properties/fields on the current object.) 
This code works perfectly (it's a [double-lock check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) pattern).

However, this is a lot of code, I'd like to make use of the new [Lazy<> type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) in .Net 4.0 to make it simpler. So I change the code to:

```
    private static readonly Lazy<IPersonManager> _person = new Lazy<IPersonManager>(() => new PersonManager(_adUserName, _adPassword, client));
    public static IPersonManager Person { get { return _person.Value; } }
```

But this doesn't work, because those three parameters are not static (they're instance objects on the current method). None of the [write](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) [ups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx) [I've found](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx) address this. I need some way to pass those values into that lambda expression? The Lazy<> class looks like it's expecting an empty signature.

Answer (score 3):

Well, what if the Lazy used the Instance property to work with an instance of your singleton to provide itself with the properties? Those fields can still be private since we're working with them from inside the class (clever), and the whole thing will still be lazy until Singleton.Instance is referenced for the first time during execution. However, the private fields MUST have proper values before your code attempts to get the Person property. If they're eagerly loaded when Singleton instantiates itself, that's fine.

Borrowing from [C# In Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx), here's a quasi-lazy Singleton with a fully-lazy Person member initialized using a lambda that references the Singleton.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
       //I HIGHLY recommend you initialize _adusername, 
       //_adpassword and client here.
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private static readonly Lazy<IPersonManager> _person = 
       new Lazy<IPersonManager>(() => new PersonManager(Instance._adUserName, Instance._adPassword, Instance.client));
    public static IPersonManager Person { get { return _person.Value; } }

    private object _adUserName;
    private object _adPassword;
    private object client;
}

public class PersonManager:IPersonManager {}

public interface IPersonManager{}
```

**EDIT:** If you have IoC, use IoC. You are currently trying to mix patterns; you're using IoC to "promote" an instance class to singleton using runtime rules, but then trying to instantiate a compiler-enforced lazy static property based on this faux-singleton's instance-scoped data fields. This is simply not going to work

Once you go IoC, EVERY dependency should be registered and injected. Register PersonManager with Ninject as the IPersonManager implementation, and then create a constructor for your main singleton DataAdapter that can be given a Func that produces an IPersonManager. You can usually define a custom function for this purpose, which in your case will leverage the IoC to provide the required instance data from the single DataAdapter instance kept in the container.

Caveat: those data fields must now be publicly readable to avoid some seriously ugly reflection; you can define the fields as read-only fields or get-only properties to prevent people tampering with them, but your consumers will be able to see them.

**EDIT 2:** Here's what I had in mind:

```
//in your Ninject bindings:
kernel.Bind<DataAdapter>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<PersonManager>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
//to bind the interface
kernel.Bind<IPersonManager>()
   .ToMethod(c =>{ 
      var adapter = kernel.Get<DataAdapter>();
      //this is why these fields would have to be public
      var arg1 = new ConstructorArgument("adUserName", adapter._adUserName)
      var arg2 = new ConstructorArgument("adPassword", adapter._adPassword)
      var arg3 = new ConstructorArgument("client", adapter.client)
      //the names of the arguments must match PersonManager's constructor
      c.Kernel.Get<PersonManager>(arg1, arg2, arg3);
   });

//now in your DataAdapter, specify a constructor like this, and Ninject will provide:

public DataAdapter(Func<IPersonManager> personFunc)
{
   //_person should obviously not be instantiated where it's defined in this case
   _person = new Lazy<IPersonManager>(personFunc);
}
```

Comment: A good thought, but it won't work for me. I'm not implementing `Singleton` using a static property like this, it's being injected by ninject as a singleton. How would you do it if `Singleton` in this case weren't a singleton but a regular instance member?

Comment: `Singleton` currently has a constructor (the `client` object cannot be initialized without a connection string). If I get rid of the constructor I need to modify my injection to use property injection instead of constructor injection, a lot of hoops to jump through just to use the Lazy<> class. I'm thinking it's not the right tool for this.

Comment: I'm not saying get rid of the constructor; I'm saying make sure your DataAdapter, which is registered as a singleton with Ninject, has a constructor that accepts a Func<IPersonManager>, and make sure that Ninject has a registry for IPersonManager and knows what Func to provide to DataAdapter. Then, you can simply use the Func inside a property getter or your Lazy field to produce an IPersonManager on demand.

Comment: My example is a simplification. There are dozens of those lazy Manager classes (which is why they're not directly exposed via Ninject). I want `DataAdapter` to manage these. All the manager classes share that client, which is why they're all children of `DataAdapter`. The double-lock check solves the problem easily, I was just wondering if Lazy<> could do the same in a more straight-forward manner. I don't want to create a giant constructor on `DataAccess` or inject all those other classes when their implementation is the same.

Comment: Fair enough. Double-lock checking should be 99.99% effective at preventing threading problems, and it won't require constructor-injecting a Func for every Manager... One last thing; you can set up your DataAdapter as a true static singleton, then register it with Ninject using a simple lambda returning the Instance as the ToMethod() argument. You get the IoC-ability of this class while retaining traditional singleton-like behaviors, without really mixing patterns at a deep level as you'd been trying to do.

Comment: An interesting thought. Thanks for the feedback and the thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

> (those three arguments to the PersonManager constructor are
>   properties/fields on the current object.)

A constructor is used to initialize your object. The arguments you are trying to pass will have no value assigned to them at this point. If your object needs these values to be initialized properly then they need to be passed in when you initialize.

Although you can convert your property to a method and pass these values to a static GetInstance method you will only setting this once, the first time GetInstance is called. This is probably not a good idea but it can be done. I would convert you Person property to a Method and accept these parameters and use them to initalize the constructor. This does mean you won't be using `Lazy<T>` and your lines of code will increase but you will have much more predictable behavior.

Comment: You're incorrect about the objects not having a value, they're assigned a value within the constructor of the object. I'm not getting a null reference exception, I'm getting a compilation error because those fields cannot be found. 

I'm not sure how what you're suggesting is better than my (working) double-check lock solution I'm starting with.

Comment: @Arbiter it wasn't clear from the code you were initializing them. KeithS suggest should work for you. I second his suggestion on not mixing patterns.